# Oreo (8.0) status bar notification icon all white

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I'm currently having problems with Android Oreo showing the notification icon correctly in the status bar and on the notification itself (screenshots provided below).

To create the icons, I am using Android 3.1, right clicking on the res folder and choosing New > Image Asset. Within that, I'm uploading an all white png (as per docs) and selecting a red background as per screenshot:

[image: Android image asset creation]

Within the AndroidManifest.xml, I set the icon like this:

`<application
...
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`

The actual App looks correct, but the notification icon does not show up correctly.

Notification icon errors:

[image: Notification status bar, opened]

[image: Notification status bar, collapsed]

Comment: create a correct icon just for notification and do not use app icon for notification

Comment: @WIZARD how plz?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html

Comment: @30secondstosam use above link by Stephen and use your selected icon without any background it should has transparent background

Comment: Thanks @WIZARD - am I supposed to set this icon somewhere though as I do in the manifest for the launcher icon? And if so, where is that?

Comment: Since Android 6 afaik, notification icons are all white and black.

Comment: @30secondstosam add it in `drawable` folders base on dpi of icon and use it like `R.drawable.ic_notify`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create icon as per [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar)

Also you need to add

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/statusbar_notification" />
```

in **AndroidManifest**

Comment: This is the correct answer, worked for me, thanks a lot.