# In oreo notification icon color is grey in Android

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

Notification icon is grey in color in android 8.0. I want to display the app icon. I have tried the following code:

```
  <meta-data 
   android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
   android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_round" />
```

But it is not working. Please help!

Comment: What do you want ?

Comment: I want the icon in place of grey color

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like that:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
    android:resource="@drawable/statusbar_notification" />
```

More Information in the link here: [Oreo (8.0) status bar notification icon all white](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49736012/oreo-8-0-status-bar-notification-icon-all-white)

I hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. May I know what is the diff between my code and yours just only the name or anything else?

Comment: only `resource` data

Comment: I  didn't understand. My image is also in resource under drawable. Should I have to change the name only?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet - Hope it'll solve your problem.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);

//building some actions...

builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
                        .setShowCancelButton(true)
                        .setMediaSession(mediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken()))
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_TRANSPORT)
                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .setContentTitle("Title Name")
                .setContentText("Content text")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.pause)
                .setWhen(0)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setLargeIcon(icon);
```

For further details please take a look at official document - 
[Notification Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications)

Comment: Thanks to answer. What is mediaSessionCompat?

Comment: I used MediaSession for notification audio player. If you don't need you can remove mediasession.